# how to make multiple database tables using sugar orm

Tags: android, mysql, sugarorm

I am in need of two database tables but I am using `Sugar-ORM` for making all `DB` transactions for storing data.

Here is the existing `metadata` in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="call_logs.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.helloSugar" />
```

Kindly give solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multiple Tables using Sugar you must create the respective number of POJO classes.

Comment: I am not currently working on that project .But surely I'll try it